# Error when opening a terminal in Microsoft Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

After creating a compute instance under Microsoft Azure Machine Learning and select Jupyter to open Jupyter Notebook, I am selecting a New terminal from the menu. However, I am getting the following errors:

```
terminado.js:4 WebSocket connection to 'wss://xalapa.eastus2.instances.azureml.ms/terminals/websocket/2' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 426
make_terminal @ terminado.js:4
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined
    at proposeGeometry (index.js:5)
    at fit (index.js:30)
    at Terminal.terminalConstructor.fit (index.js:44)
    at window.onresize (main.js:54)
```

[image]

[image]

I have recreated the compute instance with no luck.

Do you know what is the issue related?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might have your websockets blocked. Here is the troubleshooting doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks#troubleshooting

> If you can't connect to a notebook, ensure that web socket
> communication is not disabled. For compute instance Jupyter
> functionality to work, web socket communication must be enabled.
> Please ensure your network allows websocket connections to
> *.instances.azureml.net and *.instances.azureml.ms.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you cannot connect to your compute instance, and 426 means the server refuses to connect.
Could you try to open Jupyter / JupyterLab from the same compute instance?